# Image hosting and HTML img links

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image

For the past couple of wordpress websites I have created I have uploaded all the images I needed to photobucket, and then used the links from there to insert them into my HTML.

My question; is there a more stable and easier way to create links for images ? I would like to not have to upload all the images to photobucket or similar as this process is very time consuming and tedious.

thanks

James

Comment: So... why didn't you upload images to the website you created?

Comment: Photobucket also has bandwidth restrictions that will make your site look hilarious if you hit them.

Comment: I'm using woo commerce to upload a bunch of products and it dosn't accept the links if i upload the images and then copy that link into the csv...

Comment: add the images to your site using WP great multimedia features! That's why they are there for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, you could just include them in the same directory where your webpages reside.  When you include the images in the links, just supply the filename (Ex: "whatever.jpg") with no path.  When you upload your pages, just upload the images at the same time and in the same location.

For example: 
`<a href="http://www.linkurl.com"><img src="whatever.jpg" /></a>`

Instead of (like you're probably doing now):
`<a href="http://www.linkurl.com"><img src="http://www.photobucket.com/whatever.jpg" /></a>`

Or in Wordpress/PHP's Case (if pages are dynamically created, still use an absolute path):
`<a href="http://www.linkurl.com"><img src="http://www.hiswordpresswebsite.com/whatever.jpg" /></a>`
`

(Edited in response to first comment below)

Comment: this won't work since pages are built dinamically. What happens if he's 1 directory up?

Comment: He could just use absolute path-names then, instead of what I rec commended above (not specifying the path).  Using an absolute path name to his own images would be the same as he's doing now (I'm assuming right now he's using an absolute path-name to where the images are located on Photobucket).  Therefore, in this case where pages are dynamically created: `<a href="http://linktowherever.com"><img src="http://www.hiswordpresswebsite.com/hisphoto.jpg"/></a>` - this should work perfectly no matter where the pages are located in his directory structure. (It wouldn't let me re-edit my old post).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried doing this with multiple services and **if this is how you want to get the job done,**
**Dropbox** would be the most **suitable**, provided you have the **Public folder** already activated else you may have to pay to activate it because it not free to new users.

**Links for files placed in Dropbox public folder are generated automatically** and easier to use immediately on email, forum, blogs etc.

If you have a file named as `Image.jpg` inside a folder called `faces` inside your DBs Public folder then the link is

```
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/111111111/faces/Image.jpg
```

where 111111111 will be some other number (constant for your account).

So if you know the file names of your images, you could simply go on placing them in the Public folder and give `img src` to

`https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/111111111/FOLDER/FILENAME.ext`

**NO COPYING OF LINK AND STUFF AT ALL!**
Plus you could get the Dropbox desktop client and sync those images from your Machine, so **if at all the image changes (still having the same filename) you wouldn't have to bother with making updates to your HTML or even re-uploading the image manually.** Bandwidth (20GB/day) shouldn't really be a problem if limited amount of users are going to visit the site.

Basically it's like using Dropbox as a CDN.

**However if you DON'T wish to pay for an account with public folder, you will have to share photos the traditional way on DB then get the link, copy, paste and stuff but dropbox organizes all your links at one single place so its a bit easier.**

Answer (score 0):

You can host your images to public folder in Google Drive.